# Failed to display a PHP file when clicking a Javascript button

Tags: javascript, php, html

The PHP file could not be display through a Javascript button. Already tried through a "POST" method but still it does not work. How do I solve this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial scale = 1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/booklist.css">
        <title>Library Book Catalogue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Library System</h1>
        <div id="header">
            <h2 style="padding: 10px; font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif ;">The Readers Plane</h2>
        </div>
        <div class = "book-list">
            <form method = "POST" action="php2/num10.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Availability</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/oxford.jpeg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Oxford Dictionary of Idioms</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM48.90</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/python.jpeg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Python Programming</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM62.90</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/recipe.jpeg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>What Mummy Makes</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM41.50</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/chemical.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Introductory Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM124.70</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/a&f.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Finance and Accounting: An Introduction</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM124.70</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/electrical.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Electrical Engineering Textbook</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM112.80</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/record.jpeg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Guinness World Records 2021</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM43.30</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/steven.jpeg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Steven Gerrard: My Story</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM35.00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/pharma.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Pharmacology: A Patient-Centered Nursing Process Approach</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM155.00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" onclick="" id="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class = "features">
                            <img src = "img/cs.jpg">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Computer Science: An Overview, Global Edition</h3>
                                <p>Price : RM111.90</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
                    <td><button type="submit"  onclick="" id="" value="">Add to Borrow List</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
           </form> 
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
require "num1.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Practical 10</title>
 
 <style>
 table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
 
 th,
 td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
 
 th:first-of-type,
 td:first-of-type {
 text-align: center;
 width: 20px;
 }
 
 th:not(:first-of-type),
 td:not(:first-of-type) {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 }
 
 </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 <h1>Student Records</h1>
 
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>#</th>
 <th>Product Name</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Returned Date</th>
 </tr>

<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table3`;";
 
 $sql_run = $conn->query($sql); // contain SQL results, FALSE if there's an error
 
 if($sql_run) { // if it is not false, then proceed
 if($sql_run->num_rows > 0) { // num_rows will check if there are row(s) of results
 while($row = $sql_run->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?= $row['id']; ?></td>
 <td><?= $row['product_name']; ?></td>
 <td><?= $row['quantity']; ?></td>
 <td><?= $row['returned_date']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }
 } else
 echo "No table rows found.";
 } else
 echo "Error retrieving table rows: " . $conn->error;
 
 ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file could not be display through a Javascript button. Already tried through a "POST" method but still it does not work. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @UmairMubeen when I clicked the button I created on the HTML page, the php file that I created, will not appear.

Comment: @UmairMubeen, it's alright. Problem solved.